# MySQL Count function multiplying results of two columns (Should be returning count of each column separately)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, count

I have a table of users, a table of tasks, and a table of reminders. I would like to return the count of tasks and the count of reminders per user. I can get it to work when I am only counting one or the other (Either reminders or tasks) but when I count both of them in one query they are for some reason multiplied by each other.

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0d6696/1/0

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT
  users.name,
  COUNT(reminders.id),
  COUNT(tasks.id)
FROM users
  LEFT JOIN reminders on users.id = reminders.id
  LEFT JOIN tasks on users.id = tasks.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

This is what my users table looks like:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| ID | Name       | Email               |
+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | John Smith | jsmith@email.com    |
| 2  | Mark Twain | mtwain@books.com    |
| 3  | Elon Musk  | space-dude@email.com|
+---------------------------------------+
```

This is what my tasks table looks like:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| ID | Title       | Text            | Status    |
+------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | Dishes      | Kitchen = nasty | incomplete|
| 1  | Library     | drop off books  | complete  |
| 3  | Gym         | get swole dude  | incomplete|
+------------------------------------------------+
```

This is what my reminders table looks like:

```
+------------------------------------+
| ID | Title       | Text            | 
+------------------------------------+
| 1  | Dishes      | Kitchen = nasty |
| 2  | Library     | drop off books  |
| 1  | Gym         | get swole dude  |
+------------------------------------+
```

I expect to get the following results from the above query:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| Name             | Tasks   | Reminders    |
+-------------------------------------------+
| John Smith       |    2    |      2       |
| Mark Twain       |    1    |      0       |
| Elon Musk        |    0    |      1       |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I actually get the following:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| Name             | Tasks   | Reminders    |
+-------------------------------------------+
| John Smith       |    4    |      4       |   <---2 tasks x 2 reminders?
| Mark Twain       |    1    |      0       |
| Elon Musk        |    0    |      1       |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a cross join, every reminder for every task.

try

```
select 
users.name,
remindercount,
taskcount
FROM users
LEFT JOIN (select id, count(*) as remindercount from reminders group by id) reminders on users.id = reminders.id
LEFT JOIN (select id, count(*) as taskcount from tasks group by id) tasks on users.id = tasks.id
```

Comment: While I don't understand how that works, it works. Thanks!

Comment: I think it all comes down the database design, as it is unusual to have the same id on users, tasks and reminders. if they had different keys, and they joined to users like `join reminders on reminders.userID=users.id` then you could have used count(distinct reminder.id) and count(distinct tasks.id). In your original query it joined every user to every reminder, then each of those rows to every task. In my version it does each of those counts independently using subqueries.

Answer (score 2):

Try below with distinct inside count: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0d6696/12

```
  SELECT
  users.name,

  count(distinct reminders.title) as rtitle,

  count(distinct tasks.title) as ttitle
FROM users
  LEFT JOIN reminders on users.id = reminders.id
  LEFT JOIN tasks on users.id = tasks.id
  group by users.name
```

Comment: Not quite, now it only returns 1 for each column.

Comment: @Will, modified the annwer and sqlfiddle link is given, you can check

Comment: That's interesting, so adding a label to the counts separated them out? Now which would be considered more efficient? Yours or the answer @TomC posted below?

Comment: yes, cause here each task and reminder have unique name but as it is cross product so with id it is not possible. Now you should check which one is more efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

Try With below query

SELECT id, email, `name`, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM reminders r WHERE r.id=u.id) AS reminder, 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tasks t WHERE t.id=u.id) AS task FROM users u